# std::chrono::system_clock::now() considering the OS configured time zone

Tags: c++, linux, date, c++11, timezone

I´m programming a C++ code that is running on a BusyBox embedded linux. My code and its libraries has several calls to `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` to get the current time.

Since now my box was configured as dafault time zone (UTC) and everything works fine, processes running and results ok.

Now I had to set my linux to stay in a different timezone. Then I did it by configuring in the box `/etc/profile`:

```
export TZ=UTC+3
```

When I issue `date` command and the console I get the correct time, but my calls to `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` I´m still getting the UTC time, not the time that is shown in the `date` command (the correct time).

I don´t want to change all my `now()` calls - there are hundreds on them... And that is causing my processes to work with different time than the correct time, set on the console.

IS there any way to solve that without changing my code ? Anything I´m missing here ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It would be a mistake to use anything but UTC internally. Convert it to local time when you show it to human users. Programs are perfectly fine with UTC, they don't care about our circadian rhythms.

Comment: n.m. - The data that is collected from now() is then stored in local and cloud databases using a int64 format, and them uploaded to web servers. Then is shown to the final users.... Seens that I need to get the correct time on my C++ code before storing to database as I will not have track of timezones in the above layers...

Comment: @mendes oh god no, don't store local time in cloud databases.  *maybe* store the time zone used when the user set some event *beside* the universal time stamp (for a calendar app, where they picked august 12th and 7 pm), but local time is for user input and output in almost every case.  That case (time zone picked) is when the user *picks an absolute time point* in some sense (and not, say, a time,an actual event occured, or "6 hours from now").

Comment: "Then is shown to the final users" This seems to be the moment to convert it to user's timezone, according to user's preferences (not the timezone the device is located in). "get the correct time" As soon as you have more than one location, UTC **is** **the** correct time.

Comment: I got the idea. I´ll close this question and issue another one regarding cloud storage....

Comment: It is not a mistake to use local time. When a computer has to do something at a certain time, it almost always has to do it LOCAL time. For example, lunch process has to start at 12:00 noon LOCAL time. Time cards have to record the LOCAL time that a person clocked in and out. It really does depend on the application's needs.

Comment: This is why I invented Relative DateTime. It is basically UTC time, but set to the local time value. For example, if I clock in at 8:00 a.m., Rel time would be 8:00 a.m. UTC. So, all across the world, everyone clocks in at the same relative time. Editing time clock data becomes trivial. Then if you want Fixed time, you convert that time to 8:00 a.m. local time. This scheme works wonders!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Though unspecified by the standard, every implementation of `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` is tracking [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is a very close approximation to UTC.

If you want to translate `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` to local time, you can either translate `system_clock::time_point` to `time_t` via `system_clock::to_time_t`, and then work your way through the C API (e.g. `localtime`), or you might try this modern timezone library which is built on top of `<chrono>`:

https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

You would use this to get the current local time like this:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now());
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}
```

`make_zoned` is a factory function which returns the type `zoned_time` with whatever precision your `system_clock` supports (e.g. nanoseconds).  It is a pairing of a `time_zone` and a `system_clock::time_point`.

You can get a `local_time<Duration>` which is a `std::chrono::time_point` like this:

```
    auto t = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now());
    auto lt = t.get_local_time();
    std::cout << lt.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
```

Though the library has a remote API to download the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) automatically, that API can be disabled by compiling with `-DHAS_REMOTE_API=0`.  This is all detailed in the [installation instructions](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).  With the remote API disabled, you would have to manually download the database from [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) (it's just a `tar.gz`).

If you need the current UTC offset, that can be obtained like this:

```
    auto t = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now());
    auto offset = t.get_info().offset;
    std::cout << offset << '\n';
```

In the snippet above, I'm taking advantage of `"chrono_io.h"` found at the same github repository to print `offset`.  `offset` has type `std::chrono::seconds`.  This just output for me:

```
-14400s
```

(-0400)

Finally, if you want to discover the IANA name of your current timezone, that is simply:

```
std::cout << current_zone()->name() << '\n';
```

which for me just output:

```
America/New_York
```

The type returned from `name()` is `std::string`.  If desired, one could record that string, and then later use the `time_zone` with that name, even if that is not the computer's current time zone:

```
auto tz_name = current_zone()->name();
// ...
auto t = make_zoned(tz_name, system_clock::now()); // current local time in tz_name
```

---

### Update 4 years down the road

This library is now part of C++20 with the following modifications:

- The contents of `"tz.h"` are in `<chrono>`.
- The contents of names in `namespace date` are in `namespace std::chrono`.
- `make_zoned` is not part of C++20 because [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) makes it unnecessary.  You can use `zoned_time` in its place and the template arguments are deduced.

Additionally, a custom (user-written) `time_zone` can now be used either with https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html or with the new C++20 `<chrono>`.  And a good example of a custom `time_zone` has been written to [model POSIX time zones here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/ptz.h).  This can be used to answer the original question much more precisely:

```
#include "date/ptz.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    const char* tz = getenv("TZ");
    if (tz == nullptr)
        tz = "UTC0";
    zoned_time now{Posix::time_zone{tz}, system_clock::now()};
    cout << format("%F %T%z", now) << '\n';
}
```

With my `TZ` environment variable set to `UTC+3` this just output for me:

```
2020-09-17 10:28:06.343050-0300
```

Notes:

- Despite the dependence on `tz.h`, `ptz.h` is a header-only library.  There is no need to install the IANA tz database, nor compile `tz.cpp`.
- [POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) that the sign of the UTC offset is opposite what everything else uses (including other parts of POSIX).  A positive offset is *west* of the prime meridian instead of *east*.  This is reflected in the output which formats the UTC offset as negative in this example, which is consistent with the [POSIX `strftime` spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html).
- If compiling this with C++11 or C++14, you don't have [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) in your toobox.  In this case:

`

```
zoned_time now{Posix::time_zone{tz}, system_clock::now()};
```

becomes:

```
zoned_time<system_clock::duration, Posix::time_zone> now{Posix::time_zone{tz}, system_clock::now()};
```

Comment: Well, I need not a string, but the same format as the original now() but with the clock representing the correct timezone. No internet connection on the embedded system in case the library needs some external access...

Comment: @Mendes: Updated answer to address your concerns.

Comment: Its end of April 2022 and I dont have `current_zone` in C++20 G++ v 11.2 CentOS 9.. What a wonderful *modern* language it is.. You just need to parse OS environment variable to get time.. Better than this is only JavaScript

Comment: A [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) might have more impact than a comment here.

Comment: Note that std timezones implementations are OS version dependent with msvc and will throw an 'unknown error' exception with versions prior to win10 1903. Got stuck for a day wondering why I was not getting any logs at all on some of my VMs...