# How to correctly store timestamp and offsets between clients and cloud server using C++ and PHP

Tags: php, c++, mysql, sqlite, timezone

I´ve an IoT architecture composed of remote units that collects data from several sensors and stores then locally using a `sqlite3` database. From time to time these data are uploaded to a cloud server. In the cloud server there is a web application that shows logs and results from all the uploaded data.

So far, so good I need to handle datetimes and timezones correctly to avoid information mixing and guarantee correct reconstruction of data on time. Since now I´ve been handling data using only UTC datetime, but now I need to build a way to handle timezones. I´m using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) as a general guideline.

My remote unit runs linux embedded and my remote software is build using C++. So every time I need to get datetime I´m calling `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`, that is returing UTC time no matter what time zone is set (this tought is considered true based on [this answer from another question of mine.](http://that%20answer%20from%20another%20question%20of%20mine)).

For today my local and remote databases stores only a single value being seconds_since_epoch converted to milliseconds with the following code:

```
int64_t TimePointToDb(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> &time)
{
    auto count = time.time_since_epoch();
    auto value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(count);
            return value.count();
}
```

The returned value is stored on `sqlite3` field (all `sqlite3` fields are `strings`) and then uploaded to `mysql` `bigint` format.

At the cloud server, built on PHP, this `bigint` is then converted to human readable format using:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimeStamp(value);
$dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

where `value` is the stored `bigint` value.

For now, no timezones or timeoffsets are handled, and this is where I need help.

As far as I understand I need to create a new database field on both local `sqlite3` and cloud `mysql` to store the timeoffset (not the timezone, as the daylight may change timezone).

So my questions are:

- a) Is that the "best practice" or "recommended" approach to handlethe timezone. Is my strategy valid ?
- b) In C++, how can I get the system´s current timeoffset ?
- c) What is the format to store this timeoffset in both `sqlite3` and `mysql` ? Continue using the unix datetime ? How to convert the timezone to the unix datetime ?
- d) In the cloud, how PHP can show the correct time, now considering the time offset ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I've updated http://stackoverflow.com/a/39274464/576911 for b).

Comment: Where exactly do you need time offsets? I personally would prefer to continue storing all data in UTC and delay conversion until having to show data in the web app.

Comment: If it is for the local user, maybe you'd convert time even at the user's browser with java script? You should have easy access to users local time zone there...

Comment: Aconcagua, The date/time that needs to be shown is the date/time at the moment of the data collection. What is the timezone at the moment of the data collection ?

Comment: I'll write a more complete answer when I can, but what you need is called a `datetimeoffset` in many languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best practice" is to always store everywhere UTC times.
These timestamps need to be converted to local time **only in user interface**. That is, on your web pages, app window dispaying data, etc. so the time zone is used only when **displaying**, not when **storing** time.